# Mocha Sinon spy on imported function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, spy

How can I spy on an imported function without wrapping all functionality of the import into an object?

Following snippet on how I would like to test:

```
import {create} from '../../server/session/sessionFactory';
...
create = sinon.spy(create); // doesn't work, create is read-only!
...
expect(createSpy.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
```

How it would work, yet I don't want to import everything:

```
import * as SessionFactory from '../../server/session/sessionFactory';
...
createSpy = sinon.spy(SessionFactory, 'create');
...
expect(createSpy.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
```

Or is wrapping the way to go in this scenario?

Thanks :)

For the sake of completeness, here the involved files:

package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
    "test:backend": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register \"test/**/*.js\"",
    "test": "parallelshell \"npm run test:backend\""
  },
...
```

testfile: sessionHandler.js

```
'use strict'

import sinon from 'sinon';
import {
  expect
} from 'chai';
import sessionHandler from '../../server/session/sessionHandler';
import * as SessionFactory from '../../server/session/sessionFactory';
// import {create} from '../../server/session/sessionFactory';

describe('sessionHandler', () => {
  describe('handleClientConnection', () => {

    let webServer, createSpy;

    beforeEach(() => {
      createSpy = sinon.spy(SessionFactory, 'create');
      // create = sinon.spy(create);
      webServer = {};
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      createSpy.restore();
      // create.restoer();
    });

    it('should create a new session', () => {
      sessionHandler.handleClientConnection(webServer);
      expect(createSpy.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    });
  });
});
```

sessionHandler.js

```
'use strict'

import * as SessionFactory from './sessionFactory';

const SessionHandler = {
  sessions: [],

  handleClientConnection(webServer) {
    return createSession(this.sessions);
  }
}

function createSession(sessions) {
  let session = SessionFactory.create();
  sessions.push(session);
  return session;
}

export default SessionHandler;
```

sessionFactory.js

```
'use strict';

export function create() {
  return new Session();
}

function Session() {}
```

Comment: A couple of thoughts. Unless you know what you are doing, using spies are a code smell. What you want to test is that `handleClientConnection` returns a session - if it does, you know it worked. However, it's still smelling because you can't swap out your factory. I would add a `setFactory` method to your `SessionHandler` object. That way you can inject a test stub to simulate different edge cases. Follow?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see what you mean. I'll rethink the design and read a bit more about code smells / software design... :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire

```js
import {create, __RewireAPI__ as RewireAPI} as SessionFactory from '../../server/session/sessionFactory';
...
createSpy = sinon.spy();
RewireAPI.__Rewire__('create', createSpy)
...
expect(createSpy.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
```